# Why I can not Loggin in after Admin changed status to Active

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I am creating Login and Register application and I want to limit login to app by adding new field isActive

```
 [Display(Name = "Aktivan/Neaktivan")]
        public bool Aktivan { get; set; }
```

Once User is register it is automatically asigned status to false

```
ApplicationUser user = new()
                {
                    UserName = Input.Email,
                    Email = Input.Email,
                    ClientId = Input.ClientId,
                    StreetAddress = Input.StreetAddress,
                    City = Input.City,
                    PostalCode = Input.PostalCode,
                    Name = Input.Name,
                    PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
                    Role = Input.Role,
                    Aktivan = false
                };
```

After I changed this status to true User should be able to SignIn in application.
SO far what I did

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = new()
                {
                    Email = Input.Email,
                    PasswordHash = Input.Password,
                };

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded && user.Aktivan)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    //return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Ticket", new { area = "Manager" });
                }

                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, Input.RememberMe });
                }

                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Pogresno ste unijeli username ili password!");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Once I change status to `True` it still display that status is `false` and I can not login to application.
I try to figure out what I made wrong and I couldn't find any error. Anyone how can tell me what is wrong here? What I made wrong ?
I use `ASP.NET CORE MVC Identity`

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `ApplicationUser`, but only using the fields to login, nothing in the code above is setting the `Aktivan` property from what I can see; by default its false.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I am new in this field and I have no idea how to do this. Everything what I did is in code above.

Comment: `if (result.Succeeded && user.Aktivan)` Please check the condition, since the `user` is a new instance (it is not the current user from database), the `Aktivan` will be the default value: `false`, it will cause the active user can't login the application. After sign in success, try to access the database and based on the Username to find the current user, then, according to the user's `Aktivan` property to login the application.

Comment: @ZhiLv Thank you for you advice, I found where the problem is.